# How to add a paragraph on tumblr HTML editor [2019] without getting an error?

Tags: html, post, tumblr

i just want to add a text beside a picture on my tumblr, i just added a "testing..." when i activate the "view" option it seems just right,but as soon as i try saving, i get the same error everytime.

[This is my "view option"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mhIj.png)

```
 {block:IfShowAboutWidget}
            <h3>About</h3>
            <div id="about" class="widget">
            <a>testing...</a>
                <img src="{PortraitURL-64}" alt="portrait" />
                {block:Description}<div class="description"><p>{Description}</p></div>{/block:Description}
            </div>
```

[This is the error i get everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLZQ.png)

Comment: What is the value of `PortraitURL-64`?

Comment: this is just the image code, to load it

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays Tumblr doesn't allow any theme modification without updating all existing theme assets paths from http to https.

Simply substitute all occurrences of *http* in your theme code with *https* and then you will be allowed to save your changes.